# Mock static field using EasyMock

Tags: junit, easymock

I have a class like this:

```
class Util {
    
    @Autowired
    static DbService service;
    
    public static Data formatData() {
        Data data=service.getData();
        //some logic here
    }
    
    public static void initService() {
        if(service==null){
            service=ObjectLocation.getObject(DbService .class);
        }
    }
}
```

I need to mock `service` using EasyMock. `EasyMock.createMock()` followed by `replay()` is not working. P.S.: This is legacy code written by other dev and we can't change the code here.

Answer (score 0):

Given the scope of `service`, assuming the test is in the same package, you can do the following.

```
public class UtilTest {

    @Test
    public void formatData() {
        DbService service = mock(DbService.class);
        Data expected = new Data();
        expect(service.getData()).andReturn(expected);
        replay(service);

        Util.service = service;

        assertSame(expected, Util.formatData());

        verify(service);
    }
    
}
```

If for some reason, the test is not in the same package, just replace `Util.service = service;` by

```
Field field = Util.class.getDeclaredField("service");
field.setAccessible(true);
field.set(null, service);
```